# Subprocess opening the file in a new Visual Studio Code tab

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, subprocess

I use `subprocess` to activate a python file on Visual Studio Code:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("File_To_Sub.py", shell=True)
```

I needed to uninstall VSCode but when I reinstalled, when activating this code, it run in the terminal but opens the file (`File_To_Sub.py`) in a program tab too.

This didn't happen before, I would like to know why this is happening and what should I do to make sure it (open file tab) doesn't happen again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the default programs of `.py` file on your computer.

You can right a python file -> select `Properties` -> Opens with -> choose `Python` program.

Comment: Hi @Steven-MSFT , I understand and thank you in advance for that. But if I choose another program, it will open with that other program, the problem will just move to another local, or am I wrong? Sorry for the additional question but at the moment I can't do screen tests that could cause new programs to open with the code appearing. Is there a specific program I should choose so that it doesn't open anywhere and only runs in the terminal via VSCode?

Comment: @Brondby IF Very sorry for being late, you can choose the default program to `Python`.

Comment: Hi @Steven-MSFT I was doing tests until I found that the correct selection was exactly that, thank you very much. If you want, add this detail in your answer, in case someone needs it furiously, you can find all the details in the answer. Thanks a lot for the support!